# "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value" in MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery, truncate

Trying to run below query but its showing the error:

> Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Can anybody explain me, what I'm missing?

```
SELECT exam_type_name
FROM exam_types 
WHERE exam_type_id IN (SELECT ids FROM exam WHERE id = 37);
```

Above subquery returns string **36,37,39,40**

**Primary Table Defination:**

```
CREATE TABLE  `careerturn_db`.`exam_types` (
  `exam_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `exam_type_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`exam_type_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=52 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Subquery Table Definition:**

```
CREATE TABLE  `careerturn_db`.`exam` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ids` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=38 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's not a correct `DOUBLE` value. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: im trying to get all `exam_type_name` who has `36,37,39,40` ids

Comment: What is the type of that `id` column?  Can you post the table definitions?

Comment: And your subquery doesn't make sense: `SELECT id FROM exam WHERE id = 37`. `id` is always 37.

Comment: What about the definition for `exam_types`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following using [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT exam_type_name
FROM exam_types e
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(exam_type_id, (SELECT ids FROM exam WHERE id = 37)) > 0;
```

The error of your original query is thrown because you try to search a integer value in a string which looks like a `DOUBLE` value. But MySQL can't convert this value to `DOUBLE` with multiple `,`.